# How can Process.close raise error for a .joined process?

Tags: python

In some large codebase, I'm running I'm calling Process.close as follows:

```
async def run():

    result = asyncio.Future()

    def waiter():
       # Notify result when process is done
       p.start()
       p.join()
       if not result.done():
           # await result may caused result.cancelled on interupt
           result.set_result(p.exitcode)

    p = Process(target=myfunc,
                args=args,
                kwargs=kwargs,
                daemon=constants.SUB_PROCESS_IS_DAEMON,
                name=name)


    threading.Thread(
        target=waiter,
        daemon=True,    
    ).start()


    try:
        await result
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        p.join()  # Yes, p.join. Added because of the exception
        if p.is_alive():
           p.close()
```

Above, p.close raise the error:

```
    raise ValueError("Cannot close a process while it is still running. "
ValueError: Cannot close a process while it is still running. You should first call join() or terminate().
```

but I obviously have called p.join(). What's up with that?

I thought perhaps p.start wasn't called, but I added logging and found it was.

How can this error ever happen?

Comment: You're mixing `asyncio`, threads and processes, you're calling `join` multiple times from different places, and everything is a daemon. There's plenty of reasons this might not work.

Comment: The mixing of threads and asynio is deliberate (I want to call a sync function in another process from an async fucntion - is there another way?)
What's your beef with daemon processes?
p.join: Per docs "A process can be joined many times." Excessive blocking is not the bug.

Comment: Also, I get the same problem without the seconds p.join. I added it only because the ValueError is complaining about a missing join.

Comment: The documentation specifically says that you should only ever call `join` from the `process` that created it. You're *technically* doing that but it still gives me the creeps.

Comment: If it gives you less creeps, it still fails without the seconds join.

Comment: If you're going to join on it, why bother with the daemonization in the first place?(I'm still trying to solve this :D)

Comment: Because the child process occupies a port. I can't start a new one until the child has been successfully killed.

Comment: yeah, sure but why do you need a daemon for that? Daemons are generally `while True`-kind of stuff

Comment: My understanding of a daemon process is that it can be killed by an interrupt and a daemon process has no say on whether the process dies.
This prevents subprocesses blocking parent process shutdown.
Is it relevant in other way?

Comment: the notion that you can "kill" a process from the outside is misleading. I've tried "killing" processes for many years and it never ends well. Your subprocess will receive an interrupt and you should always have code to handle this interrupt from the inside. The only thing you're gaining here is that a daemon will not prevent its parent process from terminating (and receive an interrupt which it may or not handle, thus being zombified). If you want to wait for the child to terminate by calling "join" *and* close ,don't bother with the daemonization.